# Standard deviation of ratio of normal variables

Tags: probability-distributions

If we have, $$Z=\frac{X}{Y}$$
 where $X$ 
 and $Y$ have different mean and normally distributed.

What is the **mean** and **standard deviation** of $Z$.
We know, that is a Cauchy Distribution,  then $Z$
 may be approximately normally distributed. Here is the Jouranl of ratio of normal variable. [link](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v016i04/v16i04.pdf)

Comment: both are undefined

Comment: I defined, both have different mean.@AhmadBazzi

Comment: i'm saying that $Z$ has undefined mean and standard deviation

Comment: @AhmadBazzi, I worked with the monte carlo. It gives the value of **standard deviation** of ratio of normal distribution. My question is, how it is giving?

Comment: yeah but you know, your "estimate" wont be consistent

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Is there any **mathematical** way to proof that, Distribution of $Z$ is not define.

Comment: A Monte Carlo simulation (unless $Y=0$ in a particular case) is inevitably finite and so will give finite though potentially unbounded results for the mean and variance.  This does not tell you about the moments of the underlying distribution.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9143/2958 for an attempt to simulate the variance of a Cauchy distribution

Comment: Can we solve as $Z$ = ($X$ ~Normal distribution)* ($Y$ ~Inverse normal distribution)

Comment: we can compute the approximation of the distribution of $$Z=\frac{X}{Y}$$,
Which would give some different value other than monte carlo result. My question here on which result we have to believe, either approximation or Monte Carlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(z)$ be the PDF of a cauchy, then 
$$\mu_Z = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} z f(z) \ dz = \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{0} z f(z) \ dz}_{-\infty}+ \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} z f(z) \ dz}_{+\infty}$$ 
I'll leave the conclusion to you
..